# How to Add data to a nested field in Firebase Firestore using a conditional field path

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

```
var k = [
{
  "category": "Cars",
  "products": [
    {
      "productName": "Aston Martin",
      "quantity": 2,
      "costPrice": 13500000,
      "coverPhoto": "www.astonmartinphotoUrl.jpg"
    },
    {
      "productName": "Mercedes",
      "quantity": 1,
      "costPrice": 220000,
      "coverPhoto": "www.mercerdezphotoUrl.jpg"
    }
  ]
   },
 {
  "category": "Food",
  "products": [
    {
      "productName": "Pizza",
      "quantity": 50,
      "costPrice": 30,
      "coverPhoto": "www.pizzaphotoUrl.jpg"
    },
    {
      "productName": "Pancake",
      "quantity": 3,
      "costPrice": 3,
      "coverPhoto": "www.pancakephotoUrl.jpg"
    }
  ]
}
```

];

Given the above code sample, I'm trying to add a new map to the nested list, ***product*** using the *firebase.arrayUnion()*

```
Map _map = 
    {
      "productName": 'Tesla',
      "quantity": 2,
      "costPrice": 45000,
      "coverPhoto": "www.teslaPhotoUrl.jpg"
};
```

I want to only add this map only where the key ***'category'*** is equal to ***'Cars'***

```
_firebaseFirestoreRef.collection('data').doc(id).update({
  "fieldPath to the the list where key category == Cars": FieldValue.arrayUnion([_map])
```

});

And I want final result to be like this on my firebase firestore database

```
[
{
  "category": "Cars",
  "products": [
    {
      "productName": "Aston Martin",
      "quantity": 2,
      "costPrice": 13500000,
      "coverPhoto": "www.astonmartinphotoUrl.jpg"
    },
    {
      "productName": "Mercedes",
      "quantity": 1,
      "costPrice": 220000,
      "coverPhoto": "www.mercerdezphotoUrl.jpg"
    },
    {
       "productName": 'Tesla',
       "quantity": 2,
       "costPrice": 45000,
       "coverPhoto": "www.teslaPhotoUrl.jpg"
    }
  ]
},
{
  "category": "Food",
  "products": [
    {
      "productName": "Pizza",
      "quantity": 50,
      "costPrice": 30,
      "coverPhoto": "www.pizzaphotoUrl.jpg"
    },
    {
      "productName": "Pancake",
      "quantity": 3,
      "costPrice": 3,
      "coverPhoto": "www.pancakephotoUrl.jpg"
    }
  ]
}
];
```

I know I need to use the FirebaseFirestore FieldPath and some query objects, but I don't know how to use it effectively to achieve this ...

Comment: I don't think that's possible with the SDK directly unless you first fetch the complete array `k`, add the new map in relevant object's 'products' array and update the whole array back. It would be easier if you create a sub-collection for those items so you fetch only 1 category instead of fetching the complete document.\

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your `k` is an array, you're trying to update an existing element in an array field, which is not possible in Firestore. You'll first need to read the document, get the `k` array from it, update it in your application code, and then write the resulting field back to the database.

This has been covered quite regularly before, so I recommend looking at some other questions about [updating an item in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-cloud-firestore%5D%5Bflutter%5D+update+item+in+array).

---

You can also consider turning the top-level array into a map, using the category for the first-level field name:

```
products: {
  "Cars": [{
    "productName": "Aston Martin",
    "quantity": 2,
    "costPrice": 13500000,
    "coverPhoto": "www.astonmartinphotoUrl.jpg"
  }, ... ]
  "Food": [{
    ... 
  }]
}
```

Now you can add an item to the `Cars` array with an array union on `products.Cars`.

---

As Dharmaraj commented, you could also consider putting the products into a subcollection. This will allow you to query the products separately, and allows you to read the parent document without reading all products.

Comment: thanks. Concerning turning the top-level array into a map, I need it to be in a list so I can dynamically display it.  Can I add an item to the Cars array with an array union on **products[0].Cars**

Comment: No, you can never update an item at an array index. See the first section of my answer and the link there.